# Bug on fullscreen scrolling website

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estou a tentar fazer um fullscreen scrolling website. Ou seja, não quero que o scroll pare a meio de uma secção mas que identifique se vem de baixo ou de cima e faça uma animação para o topo da respectiva secção. Tenho o seguinte código contudo, parece que o scroll da animação (scrollTop) entra em conflito com o scroll da página e não consigo sair da secção 1.

```js
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).on('scroll', function(event){
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (st > lastScrollTop){
       $('html, body').stop().animate({
         scrollTop: $('section').eq(1).offset().top
       }, 100);
   } else {
     $('html, body').stop().animate({
         scrollTop: $('section').eq(0).offset().top
       }, 100);
   }
   lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

```css
section {
  height: 600px;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="red">
  
</section>
<section class="blue">
  
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que a lógica do seu código armazenando um valor em `lastScrollTop` está causando conflitos. Veja, mesmo estando na `section` de baixo qualquer *scroll* que fizer, o mínimo que seja, que for menor que o valor em `lastScrollTop`, vai fazer o *scroll* subir para a primeira `section`, o que não deveria ocorrer, pelo teor da pergunta.

Você pode usar o plugin [Scrollify](https://projects.lukehaas.me/scrollify) que já faz esse efeito:

```js
$.scrollify({
   section : ".blue",
   interstitialSection : ".red",
   easing: "linear",
   scrollSpeed: 500,
   offset : 0,
   scrollbars: true,
   setHeights: true,
   overflowScroll: true,
   updateHash: false,
   touchScroll:true
});
```

```css
section {
  height: 600px;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/scrollify/1.0.19/jquery.scrollify.min.js"></script>
<section class="red">
  
</section>
<section class="blue">
  
</section>
```

Comment: Percebo a sua lógica mas parece-me que continua a criar conflitos. Continuo sem conseguir fazer scroll apropriadamente depois da animação. Acabei de editar o meu código com a sua solução e só com a animação numa das secções e quando tento sair da secção azul (secção com a animação) também não consigo.

Comment: @ClaraFrazao Não pode alterar a sua pergunta para ficar igual à minha resposta. Já reverti ao original.

Comment: @ClaraFrazao Talvez eu não tenha entendido exatamente o que pretendes. A página só terá essas duas seções ou terá mais conteúdo abaixo da seção azul?

Comment: @dvd acho que o é pretendido é algo como isto: https://projects.lukehaas.me/scrollify/#configuration ou https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/. Ou seja, deve ficar na secção seguinte/anterior consoante a direção do scroll (o topo da section deve ficar no topo da jenela)

Comment: @dvd o que pretendo é exactamente o que estes plugins fazem. No entanto, só quero pôr a animação numa secção, a última (no caso do exemplo, a azul). Ou seja, quando estiver a chegar à ultima secção não quero que haja a possibilidade de essa ficar no meio. Obrigada

Comment: @ClaraFrazao Usei o plugin do primeiro link que vc informou. Veja se era isto: https://jsfiddle.net/eunbmnak/

Comment: essa solução ajudou, obrigada. Coloca na resposta aqui também que já a aceito

Comment: @ClaraFrazao Resposta atualizada. Obg!